# Thrift client connect event c#

Tags: c#-4.0, thrift, tcplistener

My team is building a client/server application using thrift over rpc/tcp, we have one requirement from our stakeholder that we find very complicated in thrift. Every time a client opens a connection, we need to log the ip of that connection, it dose not matter if the client calls anything, the log have to be there. So my question is, how do i do that, as fare as i can see, the options are very limited. I found an event called TServerEventHandler, but i don't get the right information there as i see it, can anyone point me in the right direction if there is one??

Comment: Not out of the box. I have seen that requirement a number of times and I think it is a valid point. IIRC the C++ library has that feature already built in (or maybe it was Java) so it should be easy to look up how they did it and follow that model with C#. If you decide to [provide a patch or PR against trunk](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute), I'll look at it ASAP.

Comment: Hi Jens thanks for that, my team and i will push a task for that into our next sprint.